# Change Document Title In Two Different Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, document, title

I have one function that changes the document title if there are notifications and then back to the original title. This works fine, it changes the title to `(1) Foo` when there are any notifications and back to `Foo`.

```
var original_title = $('title').text();

(function getnotifications() {

  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "foo.com/query_notifications.php?ajax=1",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    success: function(data){
      var total_notifications = data.total_notifications;

      if(total_notifications > 0) {
        document.title = ("("+total_notifications+")" + original_title);
      } else {
        document.title = original_title;
      }

    }
  });

  setTimeout(getnotifications, 5000);

}());
```

I also have a function that loads new content when a link is clicked dynamically, and then changes the document.title based on what content was loaded. So, new content loads and then `Foo` changes to `Bar | Foo`.

However, my notifications function is still using `Foo` and changes the `document.title` to `(1) Foo` and even after the notifications are gone, it still says `Foo` instead.

```
if(!e.isTrigger) {
  if(history.pushState) {
    if(dash_switch == '') {
      history.pushState(null, null, '/');
      document.title = 'Foo';
      var original_title
    } else {
      history.pushState(null, null, '/' + dash_url + '/' + dash_switch + '');
      document.title = '' + ucwords(dash_switch) + ' | Foo';
      var original_title = '' + ucwords(dash_switch) + ' | Foo';
    }
  } else {
    if(dash_switch == '') {
      location.hash = '/';
      document.title = 'Foo';
      var original_title
    } else {
      location.hash = '/' + dash_url + '/' + dash_switch + '';
      document.title = '' + ucwords(dash_switch) + ' | Foo';
      var original_title = '' + ucwords(dash_switch) + ' | Foo';
    }
  }
}
```

How do I get the notifications stay `Bar | Foo`?
I've tried putting `$('title').text();` into the notifications function, but that just does `(1) (1) (1)` over and over.
I tried changing the var inside the new content loading function, but the var original_title didn't do change.

Comment: Can you paste the other function as well?

Comment: @GonrasKarols I'd prefer not. It's way too long (like 600 lines) and doesn't offer any insight, otherwise I would have included. The gist of that function is it checks for the on click event of a link and loads new content in a div via ajax, does history.pushstate to change the url and changes the document.title based on which content loaded. Straight forward.

Comment: Did you tried to change `original_title` right after having changed the title to `Bar | Foo` ? Since it is declared at global scope... It should work.

Comment: @GonrasKarols I added some of the second function, just a piece.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I am doing that currently, changing `var original_title` to for instance `Bar | Foo`, but it is not sticking in the notifications function. It keeps using `Foo` it grabbed originally.

Comment: In the code part you just added... You redeclare `original_title`. Remove all those `var` in front of this variable except the very first at global scope.

Comment: You need to parse the value to add and remove the "(1) " part independently of the actual title.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Now I feel like an idiot. I saw another post tell me to change the global, but didn't show how. That fixes it.

Comment: lol... Read more on [`scopes` (simple explanations)](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) and about [`var` (if you want to learn more)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). Knowledge is often acquired painfully. ;)